# Error retrieving multiple select option in Django

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a drop down with multiple select option in my html page. On form submission, I am trying to capture all of the selected options by user in that drop down. but it throws me an error instead "TypeError:'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable". Following is my template.html and views.py

**Template.html:**

```
Select packages:
<form name=automationForm action="/vsawebauto/automation/results/" method="post">
//some form elements
<select id="package" name="package[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
{% for i in ida.package_set.all %}
<option value="{{ i.pkg_id }}">{{ i.display_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
//some form elements
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Job" />
```

**Views.py:**

```
def results(request):
    //some code
    selected_packages = request.POST.getlist['package[]']
    //some code

    return HttpResponse("Selected Packages:"+selected_packages)
```

**Note:** I debugged the code as well. The request.POST object has multiple selected values. For eg. when 1 and 701 packages are selected by user, `request.POST has 'package[]': ['1','701']`. But the code fails when I do `request.POST.getlist['package[]']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
request.POST.getlist['package[]']
```

Should be

```
request.POST.getlist('package[]')
```

Replace `[]` with `()` which was the cause of the error.

Here is the documentation and usage of [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

Also, change

```
return HttpResponse("Selected Packages:"+selected_packages)
```

to

```
return HttpResponse("Selected Packages: %s" % selected_packages)
```